# R ggplot2: labels inside bars, no stacked geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Q14 = c("< 5 people", "> 11 people", "6-10 people", 
NA), count = c(148L, 13L, 34L, 21L), var = c("Team Size", "Team Size", 
"Team Size", "Team Size")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I plot my geom_bar as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar( aes(x = var, y = count, fill = Q14), stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1", 3, type = "continuous"))
```

I would like to print the labels inside the bar, as follows. Note: my editing skills suck, I'd like labels to be aligned of course, and they can be rotated CCW as well.

[image]

Another option is to obtain something as follows, which I also like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = var, y = count, fill = Q14, label = Q14)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", ) +
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1", 3, type = "continuous"))
```

[image]

Another option is to use `geom_label_repel` from `ggrepel`:

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(data, aes(x = var, y = count, fill = Q14, label = Q14)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", ) +
  geom_label_repel(position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
                   direction = "y",
                   point.padding = 1,
                   segment.size = 0.2, 
                   size = 3,
                   seed = 3) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1", 3, type = "continuous"))
```

[image]

Note that the `seed` parameter sets the random process of which direction each label goes. If you don't like the same one I do, pick a different number.

Comment: Second option is great, but the problem is the more categories I have (colours), and the thinner the bar gets, it really looks messy.

Comment: Play with the other parameters of `geom_label_repel`, particularly `force = ` and `box.padding = ` or `direction = "both"`.